# Parse string as Typescript Enum

Tags: typescript, enums

Given an enum that looks like this:

```
export enum UsedProduct {
    Yes = 'yes',
    No = 'no',
    Unknown = 'unknown',
}
```

I'd like to write a function that takes a set of string literals and returns an instance of `UsedProduct`.  So far, I wrote a function like this:

```
export function parseUsedProduct(usedProdStr: 'yes' | 'no' | 'unknown'): UsedProduct {
    switch (usedProdStr) {
        case 'yes':
            return UsedProduct.Yes;
        case 'no':
            return UsedProduct.No;
        case 'unknown':
            return UsedProduct.Unknown;
        default:
            return unknownUsedProductValue(usedProdStr);
    }
}

function unknownUsedProductValue(usedProdStr: never): UsedProduct {
    throw new Error(`Unhandled UsedProduct value found ${usedProdStr}`);
}
```

This implementation isn't great because I have to redefine the possible values of the enum. How can I rewrite this function so that I don't have to define `'yes' | 'no' | 'unknown'`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[TS4.1 ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64966647/2887218):

```
type UsedProductType = `${UsedProduct}`;
```

---

PRE TS-4.1 ANSWER:

TypeScript doesn't make this easy for you so the answer isn't a one-liner.

An `enum` value like `UsedProduct.Yes` is just a string or number literal at runtime (in this case, the string `"yes"`), but at compile time it is treated as a *subtype* of the string or number literal.  So, `UsedProduct.Yes extends "yes"` is true.  Unfortunately, given the type `UsedProduct.Yes`, there is no programmatic way to widen the type to `"yes"`... or, given the type `UsedProduct`, there is no programmatic way to widen it to `"yes" | "no" | "unknown"`.  The language is missing a few features which you'd need to do this.

There *is* a way to make a function signature which behaves like `parseUsedProduct`, but it uses [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to achieve this:

```
type Not<T> = [T] extends [never] ? unknown : never
type Extractable<T, U> = Not<U extends any ? Not<T extends U ? unknown : never> : never>

declare function asEnum<E extends Record<keyof E, string | number>, K extends string | number>(
  e: E, k: K & Extractable<E[keyof E], K>
): Extract<E[keyof E], K>

const yes = asEnum(UsedProduct, "yes"); // UsedProduct.yes
const no = asEnum(UsedProduct, "no"); // UsedProduct.no
const unknown = asEnum(UsedProduct, "unknown"); // UsedProduct.unknown
const yesOrNo = asEnum(UsedProduct, 
  Math.random()<0.5 ? "yes" : "no"); // UsedProduct.yes | UsedProduct.no

const unacceptable = asEnum(UsedProduct, "oops"); // error
```

Basically it takes an enum object type `E` and a string-or-number type `K`, and tries to extract the property value(s) of `E` that extend `K`.  If no values of `E` extend `K` (or if `K` is a union type where one of the pieces doesn't correspond to any value of `E`), the compiler will give an error.  The specifics of how `Not<>` and `Extractable<>` work are available upon request.

As for the implementation of the function you will probably need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).  Something like:

```
function asEnum<E extends Record<keyof E, string | number>, K extends string | number>(
  e: E, k: K & Extractable<E[keyof E], K>
): Extract<E[keyof E], K> {
  // runtime guard, shouldn't need it at compiler time
  if (Object.values(e).indexOf(k) < 0)
    throw new Error("Expected one of " + Object.values(e).join(", "));
  return k as any; // assertion
}
```

That should work.  In your specific case we can hardcode `UsedProduct`:

```
type Not<T> = [T] extends [never] ? unknown : never
type Extractable<T, U> = Not<U extends any ? Not<T extends U ? unknown : never> : never>
function parseUsedProduct<K extends string | number>(
  k: K & Extractable<UsedProduct, K>
): Extract<UsedProduct, K> {
  if (Object.values(UsedProduct).indexOf(k) < 0)
    throw new Error("Expected one of " + Object.values(UsedProduct).join(", "));
  return k as any;
}

const yes = parseUsedProduct("yes"); // UsedProduct.yes
const unacceptable = parseUsedProduct("oops"); // error
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getKeyOrThrow`-method from ts-enum-util. Not sure how it's implemented, but you can look at it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-enum-util#reverse-lookup-key-by-value).

[Here's a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-37zmdh?file=index.ts) I made to demonstrate the usage in your case.

Comment: I might be being naive, but I can't quite see how this answers the question; the question wants to know how, in a function call, you can use the values of an enum in place of a string literal. Could you add something to the answer to demonstrate how this would work?

Comment: Looks like that library expects enums to have numeric values instead of string values.  The stackblitz shows a compiler error.

Comment: @OliverRadini Not sure I understand the question then. The values of the enum in this case are string literals, and OP seems to want a function to get the enum keys by giving the values as input. That's what `getKeyOrThrow` does. Of course, you will not have the type safety from defining the possible inputs individually, and maybe that's what OP wants too.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, but the documentation shows how to do it on string values, so I think it's just a type definition error in the library. You could take a look at their code and make your own implementation, because the code works.

Answer (score 1):

With [Typescript 4.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/), it can be done in a simpler way

```
type UnionToEnum<E extends string, U extends `${E}`> = {
  [enumValue in E as `${enumValue & string}`]: enumValue
}[U]

enum UsedProduct {
  Yes = 'yes',
  No = 'no',
  Unknown = 'unknown',
}

function parseUsedProduct<K extends `${UsedProduct}`>(k: K): UnionToEnum<UsedProduct, K> {
  if (Object.values(UsedProduct).indexOf(k as UsedProduct) < 0)
    throw new Error("Expected one of " + Object.values(UsedProduct).join(", "));
  return k as UsedProduct as UnionToEnum<UsedProduct, K>;
}

// x is of type UsedProduct.Yes
let x = parseUsedProduct('yes');
// error
let c = parseUsedProduct('noo');
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-VLUeTaNXO4qDYYQPXXYBbLI5JUOp0QKlIBhBkOxMNDEYW6OxsrlJVAA)

The key here is `` `${UsedProduct}` ``, which removes the 'enumness' of the enum values and convert them to a string literal.

Caveat: This only works with string enum values, not number enum values.