# Typescript: string literal union type from enum

Tags: typescript, enums

I'd like to get a string literal union from an enum.

For this enum…

```
enum Weekday {
    MONDAY = 'mon',
    TUESDAY = 'tue',
    WEDNESDAY = 'wed'
}
```

… I'd like to get this:

```
type WeekdayType = 'mon' | 'tue' | 'wed';
```

I tried `typeof keyof Weekday` but that resulted in `'MONDAY' | 'TUESDAY' | 'WEDNESDAY'`. Feel like the solution might have to do with mapped types but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

How do I do this?

Comment: That's unfortunate!

Comment: @jcalz when people 'answer' in comments like you did, the answers cannot be edited by the community. It's a pity, as this question can now be solved, but people coming onto this question will first read your (then correct, now incorrect) comment and may be mislead as a result.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

See [TS4.1 ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64966647/2887218):

```
type WeekdayType = `${Weekday}`;
```

---

PRE TS-4.1 ANSWER:

This can't be done programmatically... you're trying to convert the type `Weekday`, which is `Weekday.MONDAY | Weekday.TUESDAY | Weekday.WEDNESDAY`, to the type `WeekdayType` which is `"mon" | "tue" | "wed"`.  This conversion is a form of *widening*, since `Weekday` is a subtype of `WeekdayType`:

```
type WeekdayExtendsWeekdayType = 
  Weekday extends WeekdayType ? true : false
// type WeekdayExtendsWeekdayType = true
```

Unfortunately the compiler doesn't give you a handle to remove an "enum"-ness from the enum type and leave you with plain literal types.

---

So, workarounds?  Maybe you don't actually need an `enum`, but can make do with an object whose property values are string literals:

```
const lit = <V extends keyof any>(v: V) => v;
const Weekday = {
  MONDAY: lit("mon"),
  TUESDAY: lit("tue"),
  WEDNESDAY: lit("wed")
}
type Weekday = (typeof Weekday)[keyof typeof Weekday],
```

If you inspect it, the *value* named `Weekday` behaves like an enum object:

```
console.log(Weekday.TUESDAY); // tue
```

while the *type* named `Weekday` behaves like the union of string values `"mon" | "tue" | "wed"` that you were calling `WeekdayType`:

```
const w: Weekday = "wed"; // okay
const x: Weekday = "xed"; // error
```

So in this workaround, there is no "enum"-ness, and therefore no need to distinguish the type `Weekday` from the type `WeekdayType`.  It's a little different from an actual `enum` (which includes *types* like `Weekday.MONDAY`, which you'd have to represent as the cumbersome `typeof Weekday.MONDAY` or create a different type alias for it), but it might behave similarly enough to be useful.  Does that work for you?

Comment: Update: since typescript 3.4, special `lit` function is no longer needed. You can use [const assertions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4/#const-assertions) instead

Comment: curios question @jcalz. What does `<V extends keyof any>` do? it prevents widening any kind of string/number literal ? thanks!

Comment: is there a way to do the opposite? Get a string enum from a type that is a union of string literals?

Comment: @Pablo I don't think so.

Comment: ```type WeekdayType = `${Weekday}`;``` is wicked

Answer (score 72):

**TypeScript 4.1+:**

[As mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393730/typescript-string-literal-union-type-from-enum/64966647#64966647), this can be achieved by using Template Literal Types like so:

```
type WeekdayType = `${Weekday}`;
```

**TypeScript 3.4+:**

Following up on @jcalz answer and the comment from @just-boris, here's an example with const assertions:

```
const Weekday = {
  MONDAY: "mon",
  TUESDAY: "tue",
  WEDNESDAY: "wed",
} as const;

type Weekday = (typeof Weekday)[keyof typeof Weekday];
```

**Edit:**

Wrote a [blog post](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/is-it-possible-to-allow-literal-string-values-with-typescripts-enum-type) for those who would like to dig deeper.

Comment: That should work but has a limitation.
```
type Weekday1 = (typeof Weekday)[keyof typeof Weekday];
type Weekday2 = `${Weekday}`;
const day1: Weekday1 = Weekday.MONDAY; => works
const day2: Weekday2 = Weekday.MONDAY; => works
const day3: Weekday1 = 'mon' => does not work
const day4: Weekday2 = 'mon'; => works
```

Answer (score 64):

With [Typescript 4.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/), it can be done!

```
enum Weekday {
  MONDAY = 'mon',
  TUESDAY = 'tue',
  WEDNESDAY = 'wed'
}

type WeekdayType = `${Weekday}`;
```

And for number enums, thanks to @okku:

```
enum ThreeDigits {
  ZERO = 0,
  ONE = 1,
  TWO = 2
}

type ThreeDigitsType = `${ThreeDigits}` extends `${infer T extends number}` ? T : never;
```

Comment: An easier way to to this is: type WeekdayUnion = `${Weekday}`; That's it!

Comment: any luck getting this to compile with ts-node?

Comment: @MichaelG yes, you just need to update your typescript version to 4.1 in your project's package.json in your dev dependencies

Comment: Could someone provide documentation for this behaviour plz?!

Comment: Wish this didn't convert numbers to strings, but makes sense, given that it's overloading string interpolation syntax

Comment: what if the values are all numbers ?

Comment: It does work with number enums, with some extra work: 
`type WeekdayType = `${Weekday}` extends `${infer T extends number}` ? T : never;`

Comment: How about the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

Typescript 4.8+ has some new features that we can use here. It works with string enums, number enums, and mixed enums too.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiA7ArgWwCoQAKUAljiTCQG7ACqGJEGAPHgHxwC8cABgCQBvPHABkcAM4xSGAOYBfHnAA+cQgEMo44ADlcAI2BRm-IaLjYcBqArYBuALAAoJClUatuy4dYduw0DDAGAAm4ryCJBgAZoZwtHABQaHm+oYKcAD8cXAAXObANFAOjk6gkLBwUVgYAMaUTAjIwADCapKYuMxobAAUVGoANljAeR34RKTklDT0jCzdAJSjcAJOcHBQwDBYUBhw-UOobejFck6lFugWAIwra3AAglxwAORqLwA09wBCzy96n3uAA1ngBWL6OM6OIK4K64ABMd0c6ye3DegORcGafxqGPWAE1ngA2CFQmE4OE4ADMSJRiLR7wh62+9NeAKZcCBrPBTih52cTVUkwo1GAY1u3DGBGIZBFMwYTC6NzscAA9KrXu9lGyXtrQU4XC02jAxkrcNdemN4QA6B4LWxqjUQADWH01uqiFHEBqarXaFjNOAtPX+L3tjrgLp9KD9JoD4t6oPD6sjzujRv9nQTPTGVNtiOOueTTtdcEGA32g2GYQgUUpNM9MH5KYAAjBxABaMrAOpdqBQaDp2Om7NW63NYsJftul64uDBCDAMIYCDwRtOVvtrvgHswPsDqBD40j5Uh3GTwxQGdzhdL8yryoUDcatud7u9y+DgUx4-x09jp5CwseEL2nCQIBwVADmrSM6ytecIHvNcn0cTc3x3D9+y-Q1hz-c1LWA618VAw9UJfLd3z3T9SJw38s1PABOBiSOfOBX23FBMIPI9MxwQNgxeKIIAgMMHRTS9+SAA)

```js
export type EnumToPrimitiveUnion<T> = `${T & string}` | ParseNumber<`${T & number}`>;
type ParseNumber<T> = T extends `${infer U extends number}` ? U : never;

export function typeCastEnum<E>(value: EnumToPrimitiveUnion<E>): E {
  return value as E;
}

enum Enum1 {
  A = 'a',
  B = 'b',
  X = 5,
}
enum Enum2 {
  A = 'a',
  C = 'c',
  Y = 6,
}
enum Enum3 {
  A2 = 'a',
  B2 = 'b',
  X2 = 5,
}


type PrimitiveEnum1 = EnumToPrimitiveUnion<Enum1>; // 'a' | 'b' | 5
typeCastEnum<Enum1>(Enum2.A); // ok, 'a' fits
typeCastEnum<Enum1>('b'); // ok
typeCastEnum<Enum1>(5); // ok
typeCastEnum<Enum1>(Enum3.A2 as Enum3); // ok, all values of Enum3 fit

// @ts-expect-error
typeCastEnum<Enum1>(Enum2.C); // err, 'c' does not fit
// @ts-expect-error
typeCastEnum<Enum1>('c'); // err, 'c' does not fit
// @ts-expect-error
typeCastEnum<Enum1>(Enum2.A as Enum2); // err, some values of Enum2 do not fit
// @ts-expect-error
typeCastEnum<Enum1>(Enum2.Y); // err
// @ts-expect-error
typeCastEnum<Enum1>(99); // err
// @ts-expect-error
typeCastEnum<Enum1>('foo'); // err
```