# typescript type for all possible values of enum

Tags: typescript

So I know that `keyof typeof <enum>` returns a type of all possible keys of enum, such that given

```js
enum Season{
 WINTER = 'winter',
 SPRING = 'spring',
 SUMMER = 'summer',
 AUTUMN = 'autumn',
}
```

```js
let x: keyof typeof Season;
```

is equivalent to

```js
let x: 'WINTER' | 'SPRING' | 'SUMMER' | 'AUTUMN';
```

my question is how do I get a type that will be equivalent to one of the possible values of the enum, for example:

```
let x: 'winter' | 'spring' | 'summer' | 'autumn';
```

Comment: The type `Season` is equal to the union of the enum object's values, although `Season` is a *subtype* of `'winter' | 'spring' | 'summer' | 'autumn'`.  Does `Season` not work for you? (e.g., `declare let s: Season; let x: 'winter' | 'spring' | 'summer' | 'autumn' = s;`)

Comment: very good explanation provided in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393730/typescript-string-literal-union-type-from-enum

Comment: @jcalz I can't do `let x: Season = 'winter';`

Comment: Can you explain why you need access to bare string literal versions of the enum?  For example, why not just use `let x: Season = Season.WINTER` which is essentially the same thing?  Even if you could do `let x: Magic<Season> = 'winter'`, what would you do with it?  I want to see more of a use case here

Answer (score 2):

Typescript doesn't allow this but as a workaround, we can make it with an object whose property values are string literals:

```
  const createLiteral = <V extends keyof any>(v: V) => v;
  const Season = {
   WINTER: createLiteral("winter"),
   SPRING: createLiteral("spring"),
   SUMMER: createLiteral("summer")
  }
  type Season = (typeof Season)[keyof typeof Season]
  const w: Season = "winter"; // works
  const x: Season = "sghjsghj"; // error
```

Hope this helps!!! Cheers!

Comment: thanks, but the enum definition comes from an external library

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question.  Solved it with this:

```
    enum Season{
      WINTER = 'winter',
      SPRING = 'spring',
      SUMMER = 'summer',
      AUTUMN = 'autumn',
    }

    type SeasonEnumValues = `${Season}`;
```

SeasonEnumValues is equivalent to the following:

```
    type SeasonEnumValues = 'winter' | 'spring' | 'summer' | 'autumn'
```