# Extracting string literal values from union type for stronger type checking

Tags: typescript, typechecking

I have the following types:

```
interface Employee {
    employeeType: string
}

interface Manager extends Employee   { employeeType: 'MANAGER'   // .. etc }

interface Developer extends Employee { employeeType: 'DEVELOPER' // .. etc }

type Staff = Developer | Manager
```

I want to create a new dynamic type that holds all possible string literals for `Staff > employeeType`, such that if a new `Employee` type is added to `Staff` union, their `employeeType` is added to that new type.

For example, if that type was defined and used manually it could be:

```
type EmployeeType = 'DEVELOPER' | 'MANAGER'
```

I would like to be able to add new type of `Employee` interface and update the `Staff` union, and have the `EmployeeType` dynamically include the new type, e.g. -

```
...
interface Designer extends Employee { employeeType: 'DESIGNER' // ..etc }

type Staff = Developer | Manager | Designer

// ... now EmployeeType contains 'DEVELOPER' | 'MANAGER' | 'DESIGNER'
```

The advantage here is to be able to enforce strong type checking when doing something like this:

```
function createEmployee(employeeType: EmployeeType, attributes: ...) {
   // ...
}
```

As opposed to using `employeeType: string` as the input.

**Is there a way to accomplish this in typecript?**  Here's the relevant [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-oABl6fRjRRBxQASYhB8MQfgS+WJiPbFOBCBhoj+oo6vUrKOVdhQv4Aji-BBIDEMnxl31GKtmaZa2wzMxRiiN5v-QHwYDYeF7YUQBAg3hAA) :)

---

Somewhat related question (albeit using `Enum`s): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52396706/187907

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just [lookup](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) `employeeType` property, as it is a common property of `Staff`:

```
type EmployeeType = Staff["employeeType"] // "DEVELOPER" | "MANAGER" | "DESIGNER"

createEmployee('MANAGER') // works
createEmployee('SALES')   // error
```

[Sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=30&ssc=35&pln=29&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIFsAOAbA9gTwhQG8AoZC5CLPQiAFX0wgC5kBnMKUAc1IF9SpUJFiIUAEQgA3CHmZQqAD0ggAJuzQ0CRZGUpVtdRszYByCagBqqADIB5AAqoASmfKUA9J+QA6X3BgXOwCQiLQ8EjIALJwIHA80MqqGlo4OiQeFNTpxkysyGbRAIIAcsUA4q7uBt5+AUFQIYLC4BHiyFLswDwgSRAqEOqaGLm6+pQ5tEQmBRaoAMoAkhWl1VnIdf6BwaGkYPnIC2BwMDDIALydMnK4CsgAPjFxCUlPXT19UEIHzGnTDEOV2OpxgAG0AERTDKzCEAXSEdQAtEjkJBOMgUaQYABXEAIMDAXAgZAIKAQQIQUYAgAU0Lypn+MPyAEo9Bs4NhoGAaQADMkUyBqZB9ADuyAAJMR6TN8vxDGMILyWXsBZTqRkaUUypVqmy6qLcFAANYhNWQDV0LULYq2RZmNkUOrQKBGoA)