# Mapping Enum to Type of keys or values

Tags: typescript, types, enums, type-conversion

Using Typescript I want to convert Enum to

```js
type keys = "key1"| "key2"
// or
type values = "value1" | "value2"
```

I can do it with class

```js
class C { a: number; b: string;}
type Keys = keyof C; // "x" | "y"
type Values = C[keyof C]; // string | number
```

What I would like to do

```js
enum Roles {Admin = "admin", Client = "client"};
? --> type Keys = ...; // "Admin" | "Client" 
? --> type Values = ...; // "admin" | "client";
```

That could be a little helpful

```js
enum Roles {Admin = "admin", Client = "client"};

type values = {[K in Roles]: K}  // { admin: Roles.Admin; client: Roles.Client; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using enum I am not sure how to do it, but you can achieve what you want using a type :

```
type RolesType = { Admin: "admin", Client: "client"}

type Keys = keyof RolesType    // "Admin" | "Client"
type Values = RolesType[Keys]  // "admin" | "client"
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can pretty easily get the enum keys as `keyof typeof Roles` (it's pretty well explained [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14106#issuecomment-280253269)), unfortunately it's impossible to get the enum values union type. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52396706/4858777) of a similar question for more details. A workaround might be to use an Object instead of the enum as JeromeBu [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61303590/4858777):

```js
type Roles = { Admin: "admin", Client: "client" };
type Keys = keyof Roles;
type Values = Roles[Keys];
```