# mapping enum to a key value (with generics)

Tags: typescript, enums

Let's say I have a simple enum

```
enum MyEnum {
  a,
  b,
  c
}
```

Mapping the enum into a key value const is simple:

```
type A<V> = { [k in MyEnum]: V };

const testA: A<string> = { 
  [MyEnum.a]: '',
  [MyEnum.b]: '',
  [MyEnum.c]: ''
};
```

The problem starts when I am trying to pass the enum as a generic type:

```
type B1<T, V> = { [k in T]: V } // that won't work
const testB: A<MyEnum , string> = { ... } // usage
```

I tried few approaches [ideas in this play-ground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKClAhgGg1AIz0wGM0BfNNAFzgAdgoBBAHgDUA+KAXihSgDaAaygBLELETIAugC4obKOQDcVEgHsQAZ2pRqwHU3msdAJ3EBzLr374B8JJAB0WOVADk74oIfInBN09veylnEkD3ClUaekYAIQBGFgAVHAVrPkERcShkt0VKWgYoOIAmFLTOHkzhMQkhYDh1ADNc-KVVIviAZgr06v5anIam1q6WtvkC6LQgA)

There are some similar question (listed bellow) but I still got the feeling that in this particular example if the first option (`type A<V> = { [k in MyEnum]: V };`) is possible the other options should be too (`type B1<T, V> =` ).

[Mapping Enum to Type of keys or values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61303429/1385425)

[is-it-possible-to-allow-literal-string-values-with-typescripts-enum-type](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/is-it-possible-to-allow-literal-string-values-with-typescripts-enum-type)

Comment: For what it's worth, I think a correct version of your type is [the built in `Record` type.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) `Record<MyEnum, string>` works like you expect. `Record` is simply: `type Record<K extends string | number | symbol, T> = { [P in K]: T; }`

Comment: @AlexWayne Good observation, I completely missed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message on `type B1<T, V> = { [k in T]: V }` says `Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.`, which can be remedied by adding a constraint to `T`:

```
type B<T extends PropertyKey, V> = { [k in T]: V }
```

(using the built-in `type PropertyKey = string | number | symbol`)

Now you can pass the enum to `B` as a generic argument:

```
const testB: B<MyEnum, string> = {
  [MyEnum.a]: 'aa',
  [MyEnum.b]: 'bb',
  [MyEnum.c]: 'cc'
};
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKClAhgGg1AIz0wGM0BfNNAFzgAdgoBBAHgDUA+KAXihSgDaAaygBLELETIAugC4obKOQDcVEgHsQAZ2pRqwHU3msdAJ3EBzLr374B8JJAB0WOVADk74oIfInBN09veylnEkD3ClUaekYAIRYAFShgAA99EAATLSgABVN1BlNaAGlgOBwFaz5BEXEoRLdFFTVNHT0Dajj5BN9ISrNLavRMEMcIF0CsLC87PomA+XcCAlnR+adwpZISSJagA)

Or, as Alex Wayne suggested, you can forego declaring `B` altogether and just use the built-in `Record` type. It's definition is

```
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {[P in K]: T}
```

which is equivalent to `B`, as `keyof any` is `string | number | symbol`, just like `PropertyKey`.

Comment: Great answare! 
I figured out that I need a constraint to T but I was trying the wrong one. Thank you Oblosys and @AlexWayne