# Assign param as one value of TS enum?

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript enum...

```
enum Animals {
  CAT = 'cat',
  DOG = 'dog',
  FISH = 'fish'
}
```

I have a function who's parameter can be one of the values of the enum. How do I type that??

```
function getAnimal (param: ValueOf<Animal>) {
  return 'Your animal is a ' + param; 
}
```

The goal is for me to be able to export this function elsewhere in my code, and get the intellisense to say that param can be `'cat'|'dog'|'fish'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393730/typescript-string-literal-union-type-from-enum

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know what key words to use to ask this question, even though I was sure I wasn't the first to ask it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
enum Animals {
  cat = 'cat',
  dog = 'dog',
  fish = 'fish'
}

function getAnimal (param: keyof typeof Animals) {
  return 'Your animal is a ' + param; 
}
```