# How to define a Typescript object type based on existing object values?

Tags: typescript

```
enum InputType {
  Text = 'text',
  Number = 'number'
}

type InputTypeMapping = {
  [InputType.Text]: string,
  [InputType.Number]: number
}

const inputConfig = {
  full_name: {
    label: 'Name',
    type: InputType.Text
  },
  age: {
    label: 'Age',
    type: InputType.Number
  }
}
```

Based on the configuration above, I will render a form to the browser, and the expected output object from the form submission should be like this:

```
{
  full_name: '',
  age: 0
}
```

I want to create the object type for the expected output based on the `inputConfig` object in the previous snippet. Each key (`keyof inputConfig`) should mapped to the appropriate input type mapping (`typeof InputTypeMapping[inputConfig[key].type]`).

I couldn't find a way to create that kind of type. The expected type should be like this (`[key in keyof typeof memberInfoKeys]` is valid, but the `typeof InputTypeMapping[inputConfig[key].type]` is invalid, only to give you a picture of what I am expecting)

```
type FormOutput = {
  [key in keyof typeof memberInfoKeys]: typeof InputTypeMapping[inputConfig[key].type]
}
```

Is there any possible way to create such type in Typescript?

Comment: If you change `typeof InputTypeMapping[inputConfig[key].type]` into `typeof InputTypeMapping[inputConfig[key]["type"]` you will have a valid mapped type. But type of property will be a union type of `string | number`

Comment: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=36&pc=2#code/KYOwrgtgBAkiAOYAuAVAnvYUDeBYAUFFCsAB5JQC8UA5EmUjQDQFEBykARsAE5W3gI3HjQIBfAgQDGAexABnCnESoMwefwDaAIhLltTKNo5De2gLpQAhhtkKkAbgJI1sdJn4vMMgGawEyO7qmoLC5pL4XljKgWoAslbw8ACWIADm-HiEUJoxqpgAdHpI5gBcUIo8qWks2bkB+cAFJmHlobziEXaKUKkqAMJyPskZ1FlEPmAANlMA+iBWEMDl40RQU1bcU+U0bIvAzKxrUeV5QUUMR2K1RFZpyzhHRBtbOwCC94fZRCf+KuctDrZCT4EERKJQCjUM7xRIpdKaAAKySkAGsADxRXy9BqDEDDNI6O7ACyGbRRbQAPh0FPM4UirjyeIJQU8amxfWQzJG4NcADEZDwIAB5ZAqTJHTSo4BoHFQaVobFMoYjIJlP6xTAJJLVTRYvycpDcwkK8w0tQWelg-DdCikcoCoWipDisZHYnlADMNygkxm8325W0AEcbAATbTiIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem arises due to the fact that we can not get string literal union type from an enum as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393730/typescript-string-literal-union-type-from-enum).

But you can achieve the same thing by using `const` as answer in the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59496175/11642727).

Check this if it works for you

```js
const InputType = {
  Text: "text",
  Number: "number",
} as const;

type InputTypeMapping = {
  [InputType.Text]: string,
  [InputType.Number]: number,
}

const inputConfig = {
  full_name: {
    label: 'Name',
    type: InputType.Text,
  },
  age: {
    label: 'Age',
    type: InputType.Number,
  },
}

type InputConfigType = typeof inputConfig

// type FormType = {
//     full_name: string;
//     age: number;
// }
type FormType = {
  [K in keyof InputConfigType]: InputTypeMapping[InputConfigType[K]['type']]
}



// explanation

// this gives type
// X = "number" | "text" 
// when `InputType` is a const
// and gives back `InputType` when `InputType` is an enum
type X = (typeof InputType)[keyof typeof InputType]

// to use the InputType as enum in a function or variable
type InputTypeKeys = (typeof InputType)[keyof typeof InputType]

let variable: InputTypeKeys = InputType.Number

function func(_a: InputTypeKeys) {
  // ...
}

func(InputType.Number)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAkmADgVygFQJ6IKYwLwwDeAUDDGtgB5QBcMARFFVPQDSkwByyAtgEbYATnXpheAwW2IBfGAEMIMUJCgBuYsShZcCFOm0BZOYkQBLMAHN8RDgG1dqTDgB0FagF060QeYvsy9kiO2s7c-EKeMGLhguzSGsrQMOZ6AMLgAGamVgQkZBnIADaFAPpgcjzYdHlkMIVyAoV0AOScFdjN-rVaOHQO+i5uUF3SXXIWVTa1dQ3YTTDNAIITnRxkPZP9Ttih4kIjcRob8EFQ6WBZFtvWGyAZyafnlxoA9C8wxwBiIII817nEN7TGAFYpldpeKA+SzqIHTcaTaISWHveJfH5-bTWGq2ADSDxgAGtsBg7ic0plsttIltDMYzJZAhSLlTtHj3LZmhtmu53DINK93lREPVylBTOBBR8ABamRQWUwAN2wig2gPeAA1rKI9pIYAAfBhMaj0GDqmAAd2l2DAMAABrScHbkoo5EpwNBzXIwAATGAK5WKPhyYCE+2O7DOq028OnbbOuXyW023iaLFaggAClu9wjAEpbMTSfcc+Tgjg+eaoCAYMgILgoNaywNcAoYCmeAS3QUwMBxeAYD8YIq5D4GoVsGmcM3triSYos6X84WSWSl3HtJWJ7AR2O+BO+hucHOMAuZyEwhIND2+xLbTfMyU5Ie9LP53mpjAgc4f-ziA+I12GI82IIA)

[More](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4/#const-assertions) on `const` assertions