# Assign an enum as the value of the key of an object type

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, types, enums

Below is my Enum:

```
export enum MyEnum {
  Enum1 = 'Enum 1',
  Enum2 = 'Enum 2',
  Enum3 = 'Enum 3',
  Enum4 = 'Enum 4',
  Enum5 = 'Enum 5',
}
```

I want to create a type for the example object shown below:

```
const testData = {
  test1: {
    Enum1: 'Enum 1',
    Enum2: 'Enum 2',
  },
  test2: {
    Enum1: 'Enum 1',
    Enum2: 'Enum 2',
    Enum3: 'Enum 3',
    Enum4: 'Enum 4',
  },
  test2: {
    Enum1: 'Enum 1',
    Enum2: 'Enum 2',
    Enum4: 'Enum 4',
  },
};
```

So far, I could come up with:

```
type FilteredBuyableMethods = {
  [key: string]: Partial<{
    [key in MyEnum]: string
  }>
};
```

How can I replace the `string` in `[key in MyEnum]: string` with the exact value of the key?

So, if the key is `Enum1`, the value for it should only be `'Enum 1'` and so on.

Also, the value (object with enum key and value) attached to the keys (e.g `test1`, `test2`) available in `testData` should be the ones from enum `MyEnum`. Not necessarily all values from the enum `MyEnum` should be present (partials) but one should not be able to add any random key-value pairs apart from the enum key-value pairs. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Please provide more information about constraints. Keys and values of Enum are the same by purpose? This syntax `Enum1 = 'Enum 1'` is invalid in object literals. Please share reproducible example without type errors

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnXPBW) work for you?

Comment: @captain-yossarian The key and values will be the same. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the tricks from [Use Enum as restricted key type in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44243060/1048572) and [Typescript: string literal union type from enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52393730/1048572), you can construct a mapped type as follows:

```
type FilteredBuyableMethods = {
  [key: string]: Partial<{
    [key in keyof typeof MyEnum]: `${typeof MyEnum[key]}`
  }>
};
```

<sup>Notice the `typeof MyEnum[key]` parses as `(typeof MyEnum)[key]`.</sup>
<sup>([online playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwLIE8CiL0DeAsAFBxx5oCMcAvHAOSXpUMA0p5zATHY83G7tOFfAGY+TfHDHCyotABZJAxXK74ArCuma5AX1KkYWMMDgAxAJYAbGMCjAAJgCFkWAIYAjG8AzAYAAsIJwBnPmJ5AG0Aa2AsAC44UJgoK0QAcwBdJIAFD1grDxsAHkjyclj4uHS4OKwIADM4EzMmzFx8HLgAAwASAlbgduxmKqws-R6RfQA+Un0AbiMSAGMIRBSW4BSAEQ8YDyTrOwdnN08fPwDgsIiRexSqJPKK5mf+aVYOeQ00biSUjQgnUcH0P3IjxgALgrz+qA+QJYoPhMKRIIhb3EgIEskx8MUOOkakx4IeOxgYheInhiIE3xpClQaIEQnxTMJn2BJJmPyWQA))</sup>

This will both prevent wrong keys (that are not keys of the enum), as well as wrong value (that don't fit to their key respectively).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.