# Typescript ENUM search by value

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is the typescript code, I want to set enum in the Event object by looking it through value.

```
I have this enum -
export enum EVENT_TYPE_ENUM {
    EVENT_TYPE_ONE = "evt.1",
    EVENT_TYPE_TWO = "evt.2",
}

I have this object -
export class Event{
    private eventType: EVENT_TYPE_ENUM;

public getEventType(): EVENT_TYPE_ENUM {
    return this.eventType;
}

public setEventType(eventType: EVENT_TYPE_ENUM): void {
    this.eventType = eventType;
}
}
```

I want to set eventType on my Event object by searching EVENT_TYPE_ENUM by value. for example, I have received value as "evt.1" now I want search the EVENT_TYPE_ENUM and set eventType, the setter method only accepts type as EVENT_TYPE_ENUM.

```
const event = new Event();
event.setEventType(); //set value here by searching EVENT_TYPE_ENUM by value 
of evt.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse string as Typescript Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52370544/2887218)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this question, because it doesn't seem to be a [mcve].  You want to do `event.setEventType("evt.1")`?  Or `event.setEventType(asEnum(EVENT_TYPE_ENUM,"evt.1"))`?

Answer (score 0):

You can list every entry of enums with [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
Object.keys(MyEnum).forEach(key => {
    console.log(`EVENT_TYPE_ENUM.${key} = ${MyEnum[key as keyof typeof MyEnum]}`);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As Typescript has appropriate data representation, as you declared, it's enough to create by next:

```
EVENT_TYPE_ENUM["evt.1"] // EVENT_TYPE_ONE
```

*In your case it should be like:*

```
const event = new Event()
event.setEventType(EVENT_TYPE_ENUM["evt.1"])
```

Comment: event.setEventType(EVENT_TYPE_ENUM["evt.1"]) - this is returning undefined

Comment: check your code, probably something wrong on direction. 
Check full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/uybx40fw/